# Why doesn't this join() work?

Tags: python

I am not sure why this join() performed on a list doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print (list_1)
' '.join(list_1)
print (list_1)
```

And this is what is returned when I run it:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

`join()` doesn't modify or reassign the list in place, instead it returns the string that it creates:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print (list_1)
list_1_string = ' '.join(list_1)
print (list_1_string)
```

From [the str.join(iterable) docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks - I had thought that it modified it and returned `None`

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing the result of join...

```
list_1 = ' '.join(list_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.join(<iterable>)` **returns** a `str`. It doen't mutate the list to a `str`(!). Do the following,

```
s = " ".join(list_1)
print(s)
```